# variation of parameters for a Cauchy-Euler problem: where am I wrong?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is this one

$$x^2y'' - xy' -3y = 5x^4.$$

Then the complementary solution I get is

$$c_1x + c_2x\ln x.$$

Then after that the particular solution is

$$\ln x e^{4x} \left(\frac{x}{4} - \frac{1}{16}\right) - \frac{e^{4x}}{16} - \frac{1}{16} \int \frac{e^{4x}}{x}dx.$$

My doubt is how can integrate the last part or where am I doing it wrong

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please check out the [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to format your equations.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. I have edited your question. Please see how it is writed, right clicking on a formula, Show Math As -> Tex Commands.

Answer (score 1):

Your complementary solution is wrong. Recall that the characteristic equation for Cauchy-Euler equations is $$ar^2+(b-a)r+c=0,$$ so here you have $$r^2+(-1-1)r-3=0\implies r^2-2r-3=0\implies (r-3)(r+1)=0\implies r=3,-1$$ so the solution to the homogeneous Cauchy-Euler problem is $$y_h(x)=c_1x^3+c_2x^{-1}.$$

Now, for a particular solution $y_p(x)$ to the nonhomogeneous problem, continue with, say, [variation of parameters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650774/non-homogeneous-2nd-order-euler-cauchy-differential-equation). Now that $y_h(x)$ is correct, you might be successful in finding $y_p(x)$.

Finally, $y(x)=y_h(x)+y_p(x)$.

---

Mouse over the blue box to see what I got:

> $$y(x)=c_1x^3+c_2x^{-1}+x^4$$

Comment: well it get this

$$ r^2 - 2r - 3 = 0 \Rightarrow r^2 - 2r - 3 + 1 = 1 $$

Comment: then is where I get 

$$ r^2 - 2r + 1 = 4 \Rightarrow (r-1)^2 = 4 $$

so then is when

$$ \sqrt{(r - 1)^2} = \sqrt{4} \Rightarrow r = 3 $$

Comment: So you handled the situation when $r-1=2$, very well. But what about when $r-1=-2$ though? In that case $(r-2)^2=4$ also...

Answer (score 0):

A.N.Other method is
$$
x^2y'' - xy' - 3y = 5x^4
$$
we can realise thath
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}x^2y' = x^2y'' + 2xy'\implies x^2y'' = \dfrac{d}{dx}x^2y'  - 2xy'
$$
so we can insert into the original equation to yeild
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}x^2y'  - 2xy' - xy' -3y = \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(x^2y'\right) - 3(xy' + y) = 5x^4\\
 \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(x^2y'\right) -\dfrac{d}{dx}(xy) = 5x^4 
$$
or 
$$
y' -\frac{3}{x}y = x^3 + \frac{C_1}{x^2}
$$
integrating factor
$$
y\mathrm{e}^{-3\ln x} = \int x^3 \mathrm{e}^{-3\ln x} dx +C_1 \int \frac{1}{x^2}\mathrm{e}^{-3\ln x} dx +C_2\\
y\frac{1}{x^3} = \int x^3\frac{1}{x^3} dx + C_1 \int \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{1}{x^3}dx + C_2\\
\frac{y}{x^3} = \int 1 dx +C_1 \int x^{-5} + C_2 = \frac{1}{2}x^2 -\frac{C_1}{4}x^{-4} + C_2
$$
thus
$$
y = x^4 + C_2x^3 -\frac{C_1}{4}x^{-1} 
$$
As obtained in the previous solutions.